# Continue Button - Dynamic value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 registration pages and each page has continue button. I want to use one method for all 3 pages but they have same xpath with different id.
eg
First page xpath:  `//div[@id='personalInfo']//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block'][contains(text(),'Continue')]`

Second page xpth: `//div[@id='AccountInfo']//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block'][contains(text(),'Continue')]`

Please let me know how can i use dynamic as I used or for @id but work for first page but in second page it says element not found.

Thanks

I used or for @id but work for first page but in second page it says element not found.

First page xpath:  `//div[@id='personalInfo']//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block'][contains(text(),'Continue')]`

Second page xpath: `//div[@id='AccountInfo']//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block'][contains(text(),'Continue')]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. It will always click on the button with the text Continue.

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("button")).stream().filter(e -> e.getText().equals("Continue")).findFirst().get()
            .click();
```

Comment: This is assuming that the first element that matches is visible... that may not be the case. You can replace all this code with a simple XPath, `//button[.='Continue']`. and accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Option# 1- you can simply look for a button with text - continue if it is unique on your page.

```
"//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]"
```

Option# 2: just combine the ids using the OR operator like this,

```
"//div[@id='preferences' or @id='accountInfo' or @id='personalInfo']//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]"
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh no info is not part of id. Here is the exact xpath i found using chropath 1 - //div[@id="preferences"]//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block"] and second is //div[@id="accountInfo"]//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block"] and third is //div[@id="personalInfo"]//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block"]